# Forbidden error when using "Tag this build" in Jenkins

Tags: svn, jenkins, http-status-code-403

I am having some newly found problems with the SVN plugin in Jenkins. I used to go to the Build History and do a simple "Tag this build" to get a tag. Everything worked as expected but recently I started getting some 403 errors.

I noticed in the output that the Tag process tries to checkout the tag first (probably to verify that it does not exist already) and that's when it gets the 403. In the out put I see:

```
Tagging https://----/svn/----/branches/---- (rev.913) to https://----/svn/----/tags/----.Release.913
ERROR: Failed to tag
  org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNAuthenticationException: svn: E170001: Commit failed (details follow):
  svn: E170001: CHECKOUT of '/svn/----/!svn/ver/938/tags/----.Release.913': 403 Forbidden (https://----)
```

The destination tag I enter in the textfield is the full url, after I noticed that putting a relative or absolute path simply does nothing.

The strange thing is the format of the checkout path, with the `!svn/ver/xxx` which is new to me. Could that be the reason for the error? I set up the credentials properly and I'm using the plugin v.2.5.3 (apparently some problems with the credentials where fixed in previous versions).

Any idea how I can debug this problem?

Comment: The /!svn/ver/xxx/ is just svns internal "data format. Looks like a permission problem to me. Are you sure the user configured in jenkins  has write permissions on /tags/ folder?

Comment: I checked the permissions 3 or 4 times... it's part of a group that has r/w on the whole svn server... but then I noticed that it had an override to ReadOnly for this particular repo. Jeez I feel stupid... :(